# Failed to "modAck" for 763 message(s). Reason: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded"

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Firebase cloud function (1st generation) written in Node.js version 16 that is scheduled to run every 5 minutes. During execution, it uses Pub/Sub StreamingPull API to pull messages from pub/sub and then write them to Elasticsearch. However, the function continuously receives warnings resembling:

`Failed to "modAck" for 763 message(s). Reason: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded"`

This is how my pub/sub subscription looks like:

```js
  const pubSubSubscription = pubSubClient.subscription(
    'my_subscription',
    {
      flowControl: {
        maxMessages: 2000,
        allowExcessMessages: false,
      },
      minAckDeadline: Duration.from({ seconds: 10 }),
      maxAckDeadline: Duration.from({ minutes: 5 }),
//      streamingOptions: {
//        maxStreams: 1,
//      },
    },
  );
```

This is how I handle each message that I receive from pub/sub

```
  // buffer the pub/sub message into a writable stream

  // if the buffer reaches 1000 messages or a timeout is reached, then write the messages
  // in the buffer to Elasticsearch.


  // Ack the 1000 messages:
  // for each message in the buffer
  //   message.ack();
```

When I run my function on my local computer it receives lots of messages from pub/sub without and warnings.  However, when I deploy the function to the cloud, I receive lots of this warning and the function keeps retrying to receive the messages over and over.

I also noticed that if I include the commented lines in the pub/sub subscription above, the warnings go aways but messages start arriving slow from pub/sub.  I really want the messages to arrive at high rate because there are lots of them.

Can someone suggest a solution where I can receive lots of pub/sub messages without the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my code.  The function that I have is async function and I was returning from the function before completing the code causing the strange behavior that I described about.  Also make sure to return Promise when you have async function.  That is important.